# Guava Optional serialization with Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson, guava

I am using [jackson-datatype-guava](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-guava) along with `Jackson` to handle serialization of `Guava` objects. It all works fine with other objects but facing issue with `Optional`.

I have a serializer deserializer interface from a framework with following methods which I am forced to use.

```
String toJson(Object object);

<T> T fromJson(String json, Class<T> valueType);
```

That means my `Jackson` implementation of this interface which uses `ObjectMapper` also can only use following method on mapper.

```
mapper.readValue(json, valueType);
```

Which is not working in case of 'Optional'.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.registerModule(new GuavaModule());

mapper.readValue(mapper.writeValueAsString(Optional.of("string")), Optional.class);
```

This gives error saying `Null JavaType passed`. If I use `TypeReferece<Optional<String>>` in mapper, it works fine but is there a way to make it work with above interface?

```
//works fine but can't use this method as interface only accepts `Class` param.
mapper.readValue(mapper.writeValueAsString(Optional.of("string")), new TypeReference<Optional<String>>(){});
```

**Update**

I tried using 2.4.* versions of these library as suggested in comments and it's working fine for `Optional<String>` but does not still work for `Optional<MyClass>` where `MyClass` is simple pojo. Seems while deserializing, it thinks, json of `MyClass` is a map and converts it into `Optional<Map>`.

```
public class MyClass {
  private String name;

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
}
```

Main Program:

```
MyClass obj = new MyClass();
obj.setName("PAC");

Optional<MyClass> obj1 = mapper.readValue(mapper.writeValueAsString(Optional.of(obj)), Optional.class);

System.out.println(obj1); //prints as Map
System.out.println(obj1.get().getName()); //Fails doing casting to MyClass
```

Output:

```
Exception in thread "main" Optional.of({name=PAC})
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to MyClass
at OptionalTest.main(OptionalTest.java:22)
```

I also tried enabling default typing in mapper by `mapper.enableDefaultTyping()` but without any luck.

Error at `mapper.readValue...` line after enabling default typing for `DefaultTyping.NON_FINAL`

```
Invalid type id 'MyClass' (for id type 'Id.class'): Class MyClass is not assignable to com.google.common.base.Optional
```

Any further suggestions on this?

Comment: Can you clarify what fails? That call with `Optional.class` works for me.

Comment: And which version of Java.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis That's strange. I am using 2.3.2 version of both `Jackson-databind` and `Jackson-datatype-guava` with Java 7.

Comment: I'm using 2.4.1 for jackson, and 2.4.2 for guava's datatype.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, Indeed it is working with 2.4.* versions. Not sure why this is the case. I had taken example of `Optional<String>` which is working but it's not yet again working for normal pojo class.

Comment: Updated the question with more details after trying out new version.

Comment: Hi @RandomQuestion, do you have any updates on this since?

Answer (score 0):

The interface you are forced to use is poor, it needs to support java.lang.reflect.Type in order to allow you to pass generic types. Then you can use jacksons TypeReference (or TypeToken from guava) to obtain an instance of a Optional type.